# How to find a keyword in "nano" editor in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, nano

I am trying to find some keywords in a configuration file which is opened by nano editor, So can anyone help me to find keywords in this editor?

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the configuration file through nano editor. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and then enter the string you want to search. It will search for the string inside the file.

```
^W      (F6)            Search for a string or a regular expression
```

Answer (score 2):

Try ctrl+g. You will get

```
Main nano help text

 The nano editor is designed to emulate the functionality and ease-of-use of the UW Pico text
 editor.  There are four main sections of the editor.  The top line shows the program version, the
 current filename being edited, and whether or not the file has been modified.  Next is the main
 editor window showing the file being edited.  The status line is the third line from the bottom
 and shows important messages.  The bottom two lines show the most commonly used shortcuts in the
 editor.

 The notation for shortcuts is as follows: Control-key sequences are notated with a caret (^)
 symbol and can be entered either by using the Control (Ctrl) key or pressing the Escape (Esc) key
 twice.  Escape-key sequences are notated with the Meta (M-) symbol and can be entered using either
 the Esc, Alt, or Meta key depending on your keyboard setup.  Also, pressing Esc twice and then
 typing a three-digit decimal number from 000 to 255 will enter the character with the
 corresponding value.  The following keystrokes are available in the main editor window.
 Alternative keys are shown in parentheses:

^G      (F1)            Display this help text
^X      (F2)            Close the current file buffer / Exit from nano
^O      (F3)            Write the current file to disk
^J      (F4)            Justify the current paragraph

^R      (F5)            Insert another file into the current one
^W      (F6)            Search for a string or a regular expression
^Y      (F7)            Go to previous screen

^W      (F6)            Search for a string or a regular expression
^Y      (F7)            Go to previous screen
^V      (F8)            Go to next screen

^K      (F9)            Cut the current line and store it in the cutbuffer
^U      (F10)           Uncut from the cutbuffer into the current line
^C      (F11)           Display the position of the cursor
^T      (F12)           Invoke the spell checker, if available

M-\     (M-|)           Go to the first line of the file
M-/     (M-?)           Go to the last line of the file

^_      (F13)   (M-G)   Go to line and column number
^\      (F14)   (M-R)   Replace a string or a regular expression
^^      (F15)   (M-A)   Mark text at the cursor position
M-W     (F16)           Repeat last search

M-^     (M-6)           Copy the current line and store it in the cutbuffer
M-}                     Indent the current line
M-{                     Unindent the current line
^F                      Go forward one character
^B                      Go back one character
^Space                  Go forward one word
M-Space                 Go back one word
^P                      Go to previous line

^N                      Go to next line

^A                      Go to beginning of current line
^E                      Go to end of current line
M-(     (M-9)           Go to beginning of paragraph; then of previous paragraph
M-)     (M-0)           Go just beyond end of paragraph; then of next paragraph
M-]                     Go to the matching bracket
M--     (M-_)           Scroll up one line without scrolling the cursor
M-+     (M-=)           Scroll down one line without scrolling the cursor
M-<     (M-,)           Switch to the previous file buffer
M->     (M-.)           Switch to the next file buffer

M-V                     Insert the next keystroke verbatim
^I                      Insert a tab at the cursor position
^M                      Insert a newline at the cursor position
^D                      Delete the character under the cursor
^H                      Delete the character to the left of the cursor
M-T                     Cut from the cursor position to the end of the file

M-J                     Justify the entire file
M-D                     Count the number of words, lines, and characters
^L                      Refresh (redraw) the current screen
^Z                      Suspend the editor (if suspend is enabled)

^Z                      Suspend the editor (if suspend is enabled)

(M-X)                   Help mode enable/disable
(M-C)                   Constant cursor position display enable/disable
(M-O)                   Use of one more line for editing enable/disable
(M-S)                   Smooth scrolling enable/disable
(M-P)                   Whitespace display enable/disable
(M-Y)                   Color syntax highlighting enable/disable
(M-H)                   Smart home key enable/disable
(M-I)                   Auto indent enable/disable
(M-K)                   Cut to end enable/disable
(M-L)                   Long line wrapping enable/disable
(M-Q)                   Conversion of typed tabs to spaces enable/disable
(M-B)                   Backup files enable/disable
(M-F)                   Multiple file buffers enable/disable
(M-M)                   Mouse support enable/disable
(M-N)                   No conversion from DOS/Mac format enable/disable
(M-Z)                   Suspension enable/disable
(M-$)                   Soft line wrapping enable/disable
```

Also you can use `man nano`